# Need a pop-up saying whether form is valid or not - comes up not valid no matter what

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to make a site where there are 3 fields that come with a default value. If all the fields are filled in, I want an alert to pop up saying "ok" and it will bring you to a new site. If they are left blank or not answered, I want an alert that says to fill in all the fields. The problem is, no matter what is in the fields, I get the "try again" alert.

My JS -

```js
$(function() {
  // when the text field gets focus it gets ride of the default value
  //:text makes the browser check for ALL text fields
  $(':text').focus(function() {
   console.log('got focus');
   var field = $(this);
   //basically asks - is it blank? if not, put default value in
   if (field.val()==field.prop('defaultValue')) { 
    field.val(''); 
   } 
  }); 
  
  $(':text').blur(function() {
   console.log('lost focus');
   var field = $(this);
   
   //basically asks - is it blank? if not, put default value in
   if (field.val()=='') { 
    field.val(field.prop('defaultValue'));    
   } 
  }); 
 
  //not working....
  $("#questionform").submit(function() {
   
   if ($("#question1").val() === "" || $("#question1").prop('defaultValue')) {
    alert("Please fill out all fields");
    // since there is invalid input returning false will keep us from navigating to the new form 
    return false;
   }
   else {
    // input is valid so we'll navigate to the new form
    alert('Okay');
    
   }
   
     if ($("#question2").val() === "" || $("#question2").prop('defaultValue')) {
    alert("Please fill out all fields");
    // since there is invalid input returning false will keep us from navigating to the new form 
    return false;
   }
   else {
    // input is valid so we'll navigate to the new form
    alert('Okay');
    
   }
   
     if ($("#question3").val() === "" || $("#question3").prop('defaultValue')) {
    alert("Please fill out all fields");
    // since there is invalid input returning false will keep us from navigating to the new form 
    return false;
   }
   else {
    // input is valid so we'll navigate to the new form
    alert('Okay');
    
   }
  });  
  
      
  }); // end ready
```

And my HTML -

```
<form action="success.html" id="questionform">
 <label for="question1" class="label">Enter your first name</label>
        <br>
  <input type="text" value="Question" id="question1"> 
        <br>

 <label for="question2" class="label">Enter your last name</label>
        <br>
  <input type="text" value="Question" id="question2"> 
        <br>        

 <label for="question3" class="label">Enter your favorite color</label>
        <br>
  <input type="text" value="Question" id="question3"> 
 <br>

<input type='submit' value='Submit' name="submit" id='submitme'>

 </form>
 <p id="result"></p>
```

No matter what I do or do not type in any box, it comes up invalid and will not go to the next screen.

Comment: Why are you checking for `$("#question1").prop('defaultValue')` default value. It will always give the the `value="Question"` making the condition always true. That is why the `if` statement is getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your `if` condition.

```
    if ($("#question1").val() === "" || $("#question1").prop('defaultValue') === $("#question1").val()) {
                alert("Please fill out all fields");
                // since there is invalid input returning false will keep us from navigating to the new form 
                return false;
    } else {
                // input is valid so we'll navigate to the new form
            alert('Okay');

    }
```

Use something like this because `$("#question1").prop('defaultValue')` will return the default value defined in the input element as `value="Question"`. So, the second condition will always be true. That is why it will always give an error messsage. Either remove that condition or update the condition.
I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your "if" conditions.
in JS, if you want to have "if" statement with two conditions, you should put the entire condition after each "||" operator:

```
if (x == y || x == z)
```